# Django: Do you recommend using LTS or always keep upgrading versions?

Tags: python, django, templates, project, lts

Im looking for opinions with good arguments.

Django Framework now is at it's 1.9.2 version being 1.8.9 the LTS package.

I'm going to write a new project template and Im asking myself if it should be good to use the LTS for this particular idea or keep up with the latest version as they ship.

This last approach may lead to inconsistency and having to re check my code on every Django release, instead of making a project template every LTS version.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tradeoff is new features vs. version upgrades.

Using LTS means that you get a solid, supported platform for at least the next 2 years, while using the latest probably means two upgrades a year to keep up.  If you don't want to spend time on upgrades, pick this option. (Yes, you will still need to apply point releases as they happen.)

However, if you would like access to new features, the latest version is the way to go.  While all your friends (and their apps) are using leading edge features, you will be coding in 2015 for a while.

Me?  I'm a new features guy, so I go with the latest every time.